# Howto cache a maplayer before drawing

Tags: pyqgis

Using my standalone pyqgis application the user is able to draw moving points with an refresh rate of 1 second. These points come from a sensor that moves around and transmits data over a wireless network. While running, maplayers can be switched on and off. Some layers have a lot of features, so it happens that the canvas is refreshed before the background layers are drawn completely. This results in an unexeptable flickering.

Is it possible to preload and cache a maplayer without actually draw it, such that drawing it is much quicker?

The application is build upon QGIS 2.8 on a Linux machine, which is a hard requirement.

Comment: In the meanwhile I copy the features from the database layer to a memory layer to force QGIS to load the features in the very beginning of the user session. Display performance is now faster, but I think of this as a workaround, not the final solution.